# Problems reading filesystem of recorded DVD-R

Tags: mount, dvd

I am experiencing problems when trying to read DVD-Rs or DVD+Rs recorded by different TV DVD Recorders. Usually the problem is that when I try to manually Mount the dvd with the udf option (with auto option same output):

```
   giankun@giankun-imedia-S3810:~$ sudo mount -o ro -t udf  /dev/sr0 /media/giankun/dvd
   mount: tipo fs errato, opzione non valida, superblocco su /dev/sr0 danneggiato,
   codepage o programma ausiliario mancante, o altro errore
   In alcuni casi si possono trovare informazioni utili in syslog. Provare
   ad esempio 'dmesg | tail'
```

Which says "fs type wrong, invalid option, superblock on /dev/sr0 damaged, etc. 
And dmesg | tail

```
   [ 2525.446871] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=36641552,       location=0
   [ 2525.446878] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No fileset found
   [ 2892.059449] nouveau E[     DRM] DDC responded, but no EDID for VGA-1
   [ 4317.181251] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): __udf_read_inode: (ino 2145710) failed !bh
   [ 4317.282267] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): __udf_read_inode: (ino 2145709) failed !bh
   [ 4317.383362] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): __udf_read_inode: (ino 2145708) failed !bh
   [ 4317.484452] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): __udf_read_inode: (ino 2145707) failed !bh
   [ 4317.484464] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (2145710), retrying with the last block of the device (2145711).
   [ 4317.485948] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=36641552, location=0
   [ 4317.485954] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No fileset found
```

And this when I try to mount as iso9660

```
   giankun@giankun-imedia-S3810:~$ sudo mount -o ro -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/giankun/dvd
   mount: tipo fs errato, opzione non valida, superblocco su /dev/sr0 danneggiato,
   codepage o programma ausiliario mancante, o altro errore
   In alcuni casi si possono trovare informazioni utili in syslog. Provare
   ad esempio 'dmesg | tail'
```

with relative dmesg | tail

```
   [ 4395.151558] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

I think this is not a problem with my hardware because on the same machine W7 (I have dual boot) can read the disks and extract the files (most of those disks must then be decrypted since they are CPRM encoded coming from a Japanese DVD recorder). However the drive is an ATAPI DVD A DH16ABSH. I already tried switching to IDE mode from AHCI (bios setting) but nothing worked.

I must add any other disk (including DATA DVD and original Video DVDs) is correctly mounted. Is there a way to Mount these particular disks? Is this a known bug (I have found some short references of people having the same problem online, but no solutions like in [this discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/plug-discuss@lists.plug.phoenix.az.us/msg26945.html))?

Here is what I can exctract from one of those disks by Nero, KB, and a Windows util I downloaded:

Nero:

```
Disc Information (E:\)
------------------
Type                                                                              : :DVD-R
Capacity                                                                          : 487:54.50  (828 MB)
Tracks                                                                            : 3
Sessions                                                                          : 1

File System                                                                       : , UDF
Title                                                                             : n/a
Date                                                                              : n/a
Publisher                                                                         : n/a
Application                                                                       : n/a
```

KB:

```
Medium

Type:   DVD-R Sequential
Media ID:   MXL RG04
Capacity:   487:54:50 min (4,2 GiB)
Used Capacity:  487:54:50 min (4,2 GiB)
Remaining:  00:00:00 min (0 B)
Rewritable: no
Appendable: no
Empty:  no
Layers: 1
Sessions:   1
Supported writing speeds:   6.0x (8310 KB/s)
8.0x (11080 KB/s)
12.0x (16620 KB/s)
16.0x (22160 KB/s)
ISO9660 Filesystem Info

System Id:  -
Volume Id:  -
Volume Set Id:  -
Publisher Id:   -
Preparer Id:    -
Application Id: -
Volume Size:    0 B (0 B * 0 blocks = 0 B)
Tracks

Type    Attributes  First-Last Sector   Length
1   (Data)  no copy/uninterrupted   0 - 543 544 (00:07:19)
2   (Data)  no copy/uninterrupted   560 - 831   272 (00:03:47)
3   (Data)  no copy/uninterrupted   848 - 2195599   2194752 (487:43:27)
```

Dvd Info:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unique Disc Identifier : [DVD-R:MXL RG04]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disc & Book Type :       [DVD-R] - [DVD-R]
Manufacturer Name :      [Hitachi Maxell Ltd.]
Manufacturer ID :        [MXL RG04]
Blank Disc Capacity :    [2,298,496 Sectors = 4.71 GB (4.38 GiB)]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ DVD Identifier V5.2.0 - http://DVD.Identifier.CDfreaks.com ]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------


** INFO : Hex Dump Of 'Media Code'-Block Listed Below
** INFO : 4-Byte Header Preceding 'Media Code'-Block Discarded
** INFO : Format 0Eh - Pre-Recorded Information In Lead-In
0000 : 01 40 c1 fd 9e d8 52 00  02 85 0e 0d 99 ab 80 00   .@....R.........
0010 : 03 4d 58 4c 20 52 47 00  04 30 34 00 00 00 00 00   .MXL RG..04.....
0020 : 05 88 80 00 00 00 02 00  06 09 0b 15 87 78 90 00   .............x..
0030 : 07 88 80 00 00 00 00 00  08 08 13 0d 11 0c 08 00   ................
0040 : 09 95 07 0e 0b 78 88 00  0a a0 00 20 00 20 10 00   .....x..... . ..
0050 : 0b 09 19 17 97 88 85 00  0c b6 89 2b 82 30 23 00   ...........+.0#.
0060 : 0d 00 00 d0 00 00 00 00  00 00                     ..........      

** INFO : Hex Dump Of 'Control Data Zone'-Block Listed Below
** INFO : 4-Byte Header Preceding 'CDZ'-Block Discarded
** INFO : Format 10h - Physical Format Information Of Control Data Zone
0000 : 25 0f 02 00 00 03 00 00  00 26 12 7f 00 00 00 00   %........&......
```

Comment: I couldn't find any specific information to confirm, but my guess would be that CPRM is encrypting or modifying the UDF file structures too so the disk does not look like a regular UDF filesystem. If this is the case you are most likely out of luck unless you can persuade the DVD recorder not to do this. Have you tried "finalising" the disk in the recorder?

Comment: The disks are finalised and are readily read by the same Pc on Windows 7. However at first I also suspected there was something problematic related to the encryption, so I tried to read non cprm encrypted disks (made from an Italian DVD recorder) and the problem is the same. (I will add that the encryption is breakable with a program I would run from Wine, but the program needs to access the DVD to get the key).

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the filesystem type:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/x/dvd -t FILESYSTEMTYPE
```

Options are:

> > auto - this is a special one. It will try to guess the fs type when you use this.
> >
> > ext4 - this is probably the most common Linux fs type of the last few years
> >
> > ext3 - this is the most common Linux fs type from a couple years back
> >
> > ntfs - this is the most common Windows fs type or larger external hard drives
> >
> > vfat - this is the most common fs type used for smaller external hard drives
> >
> > iso9660 mostly for CDs
> >
> > udf mostly for DVD on newer windows

**cd and dvd filesystems are mostly iso9660 or udf**

Comment: If I set no options (like in the example above) mount already tries to use UDF with the result above. I also tried to force Mount to read  the disk as iso9660 with different error, but no success. Now I am at work (on Windows), I will get more outputs this evening.

Comment: Edited the original question to show what happens if I try to mount with the -t option.

Comment: @Giankun please use any cd/dvd burning tool such as k3b and post this dvd Media Info

Comment: I will tonight, after I restore my dual boot (sigh, this morning Windows would not boot anymore and this means I have to restore it and then repair grub).

Comment: Btw I just noticed the reading those Dvd is not sure in W7 systems too. I brought some at work and the DVD reader I am using - MATSHITA CD-RW CW-8124 ATA DEVICE) won't be able to read some of them (Others are read, but Relcprm won't extract the key, meaning some sectors look unreadable from this particular hardware). What baffles me is that I can do what I want with my system in Windows, but not in Linux. And it makes me angry that all the protections won't stop me from downloading movies still in the cinemas, but make it really hard to show my 2 yo son movies is grandaddy lawfully recorded.

Comment: Hang on, I needed to make a clean reinstall of Windows 7 tonight and then restore Grub (everything worked fine, still have to finish upgrading W7 though), but I did not have the time to check the dvd Media info and data.

Comment: @Giankun I am waiting take your time

Comment: ok done, Yesterday evening I posted the disk info.